# Using MassTransit to connect to Confluent Cloud not working

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, masstransit, confluent-cloud

I tried with the following set up to connect securely to the Confluent Cloud environment through MassTransit, but it seems not be working. I'm trying to make this work in .NET Core:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((busRegistryContext, rabbitMQBusFactory) => rabbitMQBusFactory.ConfigureEndpoints(busRegistryContext));

    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddProducer<UserEvent>(topicName: "UserCreated");
        rider.AddProducer<UserEvent>(topicName: "UserUpdated");
        rider.AddProducer<UserEvent>(topicName: "UserDeleted");

        rider.AddConsumer<UserCreatedEventConsumer>();

        rider.UsingKafka((riderContext, kafkaFactory) => 
        {
            kafkaFactory.SecurityProtocol = Confluent.Kafka.SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl;

            kafkaFactory.Host(server: "[hided...].westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092", configureHost =>
            {
                configureHost.UseSasl(saslConfig =>
                {
                saslConfig.Mechanism = Confluent.Kafka.SaslMechanism.Plain;
                saslConfig.Username = "...................";
                saslConfig.Password = "...................";
                });
            });

            var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig()
            {
                GroupId = "dotnet-example-group-1",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
                EnableAutoCommit = false
            };

            kafkaFactory.TopicEndpoint<UserCreatedEvent>(
                topicName: "UserCreated", consumerConfig, kafkaTopicReceiveEndpointConfig =>
            {
                kafkaTopicReceiveEndpointConfig.ConfigureConsumer<UserCreatedEventConsumer>(riderContext);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
MassTransit: Warning: Connection Failed: rabbitmq://localhost/

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TcpClientAdapter.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TaskExtensions.TimeoutAfter(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingAddressFamily(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout, AddressFamily family)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ConnectionContextFactory.CreateConnection(ISupervisor supervisor)
```

I actually expected to just connect to my Confluent Cloud Kafka cluster, but I'm new to MassTransit and Confluent Cloud and don't get it why this is happening (Although I followed some tutorials and read through MassTransit documentation carefully)

Comment: The failure is connecting to RabbitMQ, not Confluent Cloud.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson any ideas how I could solve this problem, because I've been searching for a solution but can't really find one...

Comment: Even though I declare: server: "[hided...].westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092". It still said "rabbitmq://localhost/" localhost? Like how is this even possible?

Comment: Uh.... `x.UsingRabbitMq((busRegistryContext, rabbitMQBusFactory) => rabbitMQBusFactory.ConfigureEndpoints(busRegistryContext));`

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I already had that line of code, what are you trying to say here?

Comment: As stated in my first comment, the error you posted has NOTHING to do with Confluent Cloud. It's indicating that there isn't a RabbitMQ broker running on localhost. Two completely separate things, so your question isn't valid.

Comment: No @ChrisPatterson, let me explain it. Basically, Confluent Cloud provides me with a Apache Kafka cluster where I have my topics. MassTransit provides a solution where it uses RabbitMQ as the transport protocol/layer to transmit messages to a Apache Kafka cluster. If you read the MassTransit documentation, they say that this is possible. However, if I try to do this on a cluster that is managed through Confluent Cloud, than suddenly it won't work. I'm sure there is a way, it is just that there is not much to find on the internet but I'm very sure that this can be done.

Comment: And by the way, you still did not respond to my earlier question. You literally posted a line of code that already was written within my question. I'm still confused why you posted something which is totally irrelevant to point out as a 'solution', just after I asked 'Any ideas how I could solve this problem...'

Comment: You do realize I wrote MassTransit right? So I know how it works. Get rid of RabbitMQ, entirely. You don't even know what you're talking about. Replace it with `x.UsingInMemory()`.

Comment: Oh, wait? My apologies. I did not want to disrespect you in any way... When you just pasted that line of code, I really was confused... And I guess, I do not know what I'm talking about. I really thought that it was using RabbitMQ transport layer to transport the messages? I will try it and come back to you.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thank you very much, you really helped me through and it worked. I'm only wondering something, because it really bothers me. How can I provide an abstract type for the producer, so that I can do something like: rider.AddProducer<UserEvent>(topicName: "UserCreated"); rider.AddProducer<UserEvent>(topicName: "UserUpdated"); Then when I inject the the interface like this: ITopicProducer<UserEvent> producer .. -> whereafter I try to send the concrete class producer.Produce(new UserCreatedEvent(args...)) but this seems not to be working. It works only if you define concrete types?

Comment: Another thing I was wondering, is that InMemory is not recommended for production use. With which transport protocol would I replace InMemory to make this work in this circumstance using the Confluent Cloud?

Comment: Kafka is the transport, in-memory is the bus which isn't used if you're producing and consuming from Kafka. And you must create producers for the actual message types to ensure they are serialized properly. End of line, asking questions in comments is highly discouraged.

Comment: All right, your explanation enlightened me. I want to thank you again for the effort and helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The way I solved it is as follows:**

- Program.cs → Inject MassTransit within the Dependency Injection container
- Controllers → Only inject ITopicProducer for the declared producers
- Custom classes → for consuming messages

P.S. keep in mind that if you want to load balance between various consumers, you might want to use different consumer group ids. Partitions will than be divided within these consumer groups. Please see: [Consumer Groups](https://www.stackchief.com/questions/What%20is%20Kafka%20Consumer%20Group%20ID%3F)

One more thing: you do not have to inject the IHostedService anymore with MassTransit, since services.AddMassTransit()... does this for you.

**For people who are new to the concept of 'messaging' like me...**

You can choose whether or not to include the consumer within Program.cs. If you do so, you will just receive the payload within the same project. Let's say you define the producer in one project and the consumer in another, then the producer will send the message to the Kafka topic and the consumer within that other project will read from this topic and will receive the message.

**Program.cs**

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using MassTransit;

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });

    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        // Producers
        rider.AddProducer<UserCreatedEvent>(topicName: "UserCreated");//Example 1
        rider.AddProducer<UserUpdatedEvent>(topicName: "UserUpdated");//Example 2
        rider.AddProducer<UserDeletedEvent>(topicName: "UserDeleted");//Example 3

        // Consumers
        rider.AddConsumer<UserCreatedEventConsumer>();

        // Apache Kafka configuration
        rider.UsingKafka((riderContext, kafkaFactory) => 
        {
            kafkaFactory.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl;

            kafkaFactory.Host("[hided...].westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092", configureHost =>
            {
                configureHost.UseSasl(saslConfig =>
                {
                    saslConfig.Mechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain;
                    saslConfig.Username = ".....PUT HERE YOUR API KEY.........";
                    saslConfig.Password = ".....PUT HERE YOUR API SECRET......";
                });
            });

            var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig()
            {
                // If you have 4 consumers and you want to divide them within for example 8 partitions -> use the same group id for the consumers you want the partitions assigned to
                // If you, for instance use the same group id for 3 consumers and the 4th has another group id, then the partitions will be divided in such a way that 3 consumers will be 
                // assigned from 0 to 6 partitions and the 4th will only consume from the 7th partition.. 
                // Using partitions enables consumers to read in parallel which is convenient for consumers to consume at the same time..
                GroupId = "dotnet-example-group-2",

                //Keep in mind that this will start from where the offset was left (offset is a unique number for each message)
                // You can also use 'Earliest', but this will always pull everything in!
                // In case of down time of an application, you could do additional check to see whether or not something was already processed
                // Just to be sure (within your custom class that consumes messages)
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,

                EnableAutoCommit = false,
                // Use Property for Sasl Username for Consumer (only if needed)
                // Use Property Sasl Password for Consumer (only if needed)
            };

            // Put here your consumer endpoints (Configuration of how to receive messages and from which topic incl. settings from consumerConfig)
            kafkaFactory.TopicEndpoint<UserCreatedEvent>(
            topicName: "UserCreated", consumerConfig, kafkaTopicReceiveEndpointConfig =>
            {
                kafkaTopicReceiveEndpointConfig.ConfigureConsumer<UserCreatedEventConsumer>(riderContext);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestController 
{
    private readonly ITopicProducer<UserCreatedEvent> userCreatedProducer;
    private readonly ITopicProducer<UserUpdatedEvent> userUpdatedProducer;
    private readonly ITopicProducer<UserDeletedEvent> userDeletedProducer;

    public AuthController(
        ITopicProducer<UserCreatedEvent> userCreatedProducer,
        ITopicProducer<UserUpdatedEvent> userUpdatedProducer,
        ITopicProducer<UserDeletedEvent> userDeletedProducer)
   {
       this.userCreatedProducer = userCreatedProducer;
       this.userUpdatedProducer = userUpdatedProducer;
       this.userDeletedProducer = userDeletedProducer;
   }

    [HttpGet(nameof(TestKafka))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestKafka()
    {
        await userCreatedProducer.Produce(new UserCreatedEvent()
        {
            EventId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Value = new User() 
            { 
                Id = 1, 
                Username = "Apache_Kafka_Test_User"
            }
        });

        await userUpdatedProducer.Produce(new UserUpdatedEvent()
        {
            EventId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Value = new User()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Username = "Apache_Kafka_Test_User_Updated"
            }
        });

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Custom classes: Message Classes**

```
public class UserCreatedEvent
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public UserCreatedEvent()
    {

    }
}

public class UserUpdatedEvent
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public UserUpdatedEvent()
    {
        
    }
}
```

**Custom classes: Consumer Message Classes for MassTransit**

```
public class UserCreatedEventConsumer : IConsumer<UserCreatedEvent>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<UserCreatedEvent> context)
    {
        _ = context.Message.EventId;
        _ = context.Message.Value;

        Debug.WriteLine($"EventId: {context.Message.EventId}");
        Debug.WriteLine(context.Message.Value);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class UserUpdatedEventConsumer : IConsumer<UserUpdatedEvent>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<UserUpdatedEvent> context)
    {
        _ = context.Message.EventId;
        _ = context.Message.Value;

        Debug.WriteLine($"EventId: {context.Message.EventId}");
        Debug.WriteLine(context.Message.Value);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```